Blender does not recognize keymap context, even though all works fine when running some parts of the function separately
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Blender\stable\blender-4.2.3-lts+stable.0e22e4fcea03\4.2\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 238, in register_module_call
    register()
  File "C:\Blender\stable\blender-4.2.3-lts+stable.0e22e4fcea03\4.2\scripts\startup\HEAVYPOLY_HOTKEYS.py", line 210, in register
    Keymap_Register()
  File "C:\Blender\stable\blender-4.2.3-lts+stable.0e22e4fcea03\4.2\scripts\startup\HEAVYPOLY_HOTKEYS.py", line 116, in Keymap_Register
    km = get_keymap_items_ctx('Blender', 'Node Editor')
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Blender\stable\blender-4.2.3-lts+stable.0e22e4fcea03\4.2\scripts\startup\HEAVYPOLY_HOTKEYS.py", line 18, in get_keymap_items_ctx
    return window_manager.keyconfigs[keymap_config].keymaps[keymap_context].keymap_items
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Node Editor" not found'

this is the error I get for this script: https://github.com/HannahFantasia/HANNAH_Blender/blob/master/scripts/startup/HEAVYPOLY_HOTKEYS.py
import bpy
window_manager = bpy.context.window_manager
for keymap_name, keymap in window_manager.keyconfigs['Blender'].keymaps.items():
    print(f"Keymap: {keymap_name}")

here 'Node Editor' does show
